# tiled textures across a google map in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Using the google maps v3 javascript API, it's possible to add 'GroundOverlays' as a picture. Have a look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9YYJB/1/

However, I'm working on a project where I'm trying to add a texture to the *whole* world map. Obviously I can add a single, absolutely massive gif/png overlay but I'd rather add a tiling texture. I've been digging around in the API and can't find any way to do this.

Anyone have any ideas on how this could be done?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you want to use is an [image map type](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#ImageMapTypes). This allows you to add tiles on top of the regular Google Base Map. If you want to completely replace the Google tiles, you would need to implement a [Custom Map Type](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#CustomMapTypes). My favorite example of that is the [Liberty City Map](http://www.gta4.net/map/).

Comment: any information on how best to do this?  I"ve been playing around with this but Google's docs are woefully inadequate at best.  How do I know how to slice up my image for each zoom level?

Comment: any chance on some code snippets as tkone said it's very sparsely documented and looks pretty powerful. could you point to a simple example anywhere which you have seen?